# Rows in a table, selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

My goal i to loop over each row of this table in selenium, and I cannot grab the specific rows / messages.

```
for row in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'msg')]"):
    print row.text
```

I know there has to be a better way of doing this, my end goal is to retrieve the two messages. "hello" and "hellow". Any help or suggestions would be awesome. Ive tried getting the element by the by_class_name "nme pn_std" but it glitches because it doesnt like classes that are two words

```
<body>
  <table id="mt" class="hbtbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1">
        <td id="m1" class="msg stxt2 g1">
          <div class="dtxt2">
            24 Feb 16, 04:17 PM
          </div><span class="modtools" id="mod_1">
          </span><b class="nme pn_std">k223</b>: hello
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="2">
        <td id="m2" class="msg stxt g1">
          <div class="dtxt">
            24 Feb 16, 04:17 PM
          </div><span class="modtools" id="mod_2">
          </span><b class="nme pn_std">c9e</b>: hellow
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: As of now there are no errors thanks :) Its just now my code is not printing anything, something is wrong with my xpath I believe.

Comment: `..ive been having some trouble` what trouble? are you getting an error? if so, what's the error?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I've changed the question I believe. Changed the beginning and added an edit at the bottom.

Comment: are you sure the browser is launching correctly?  also, just humor me.. what happens when you do `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.msg')`

Comment: Figured it out :) I had to switch to the iframe! driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME,"cboxmain")) Thanks for your help

Comment: ah yes :)  that would make sense.  that was my next question.. glad you figured it out!

Comment: "classes that are two words": **no such thing**! It is a space-separated **list** of classes! Have you tried just `by_class_name("nme")`?

Comment: Great to know :) Thanks!